# How do I solve this making it more efficient?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

So, I am trying to solve the following question: https://www.codechef.com/TSTAM15/problems/ACM14AM3

> > *The Mars Orbiter Mission probe lifted-off from the First Launch Pad at Satish Dhawan Space Centre (Sriharikota Range SHAR), Andhra
> >     Pradesh, using a Polar Satellite Launch Vehicle (PSLV) rocket C25 at
> >     09:08 UTC (14:38 IST) on 5 November 2013.*
>
> The secret behind this successful launch was the launch pad that ISRO
>   used. An important part of the launch pad is the launch tower. It is
>   the long vertical structure which supports the rocket.
>
> ISRO now wants to build a better launch pad for their next mission.
>   For this, ISRO has acquired a long steel bar, and the launch tower can
>   be made by cutting a segment from the bar. As part of saving the cost,
>   the bar they have acquired is not homogeneous.
>
> The bar is made up of several blocks, where the ith block has
>   durability S[i], which is a number between 0 and 9. A segment is
>   defined as any contiguous group of one or more blocks.
>
> If they cut out a segment of the bar from *ith* block to *jth* block
>   (i<=j), then the durability of the resultant segment is given by `(S[i]*10(j-i) + S[i+1]*10(j-i-1) + S[i+2]*10(j-i-2) + … + S[j] * 10(0)) % M`. In other words, if `W(i,j)` is the base-10 number formed by
>   concatenating the digits `S[i]`, `S[i+1]`, `S[i+2]`, …, `S[j]`, then
>   the durability of the segment `(i,j)` is `W(i,j) % M`.
>
> For technical reasons that ISRO will not disclose, the durability of
>   the segment used for building the launch tower should be exactly L.
>   Given S and M, find the number of ways ISRO can cut out a segment from
>   the steel bar whose durability is L. Input
>
> The first line contains a string S. The ith character of this string
>   represents the durability of ith segment. The next line contains a
>   single integer Q, denoting the number of queries. Each of the next Q
>   lines contain two space separated integers, denoting M and L. Output
>
> For each query, output the number of ways of cutting the bar on a
>   separate line. Constraints
>
> ```
> 1 ≤ |S| ≤ 2 * 10^4
> Q ≤ 5
> 0 < M < 500
> 0 ≤ L < M
> ```
>
> ---
>
> #### Example
>
> <sub>**Input**</sub>:
>
> ```
> 23128765
> 3
> 7 2
> 9 3
> 15 5
> ```
>
> <sub>**Output**</sub>:
>
> ```
> 9
> 4
> 5
> ```
>
> <sub>**Explanation**</sub>
>
> For `M=9`, `L=3`, the substrings whose remainder is 3 when divided by
>   9 are: 3, 31287, 12 and 876.

Now, what I did was, I initially generate all possible substrings of numbers of the given length, and tried to divide it by the given number to check if it is divisible and added it to the answer. Therefore, my code for the same was,

```
string s;
    cin>>s;
    int m,l,ans=0;
    for ( i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
    {
        for ( j = i+1; j < s.length(); j++ )
        {
            string p = s.substr(i,j);
            long long num = stoi(p);
            if (num%m == l)
                ans++;
        }
    }
    cout<<ans<<"\n";
    return 0;
```

But obviously since the input length is upto 10^4, this doesn't work in required time. How can I make it more optimal?

Comment: That's not the whole code, as `i` and `j` are not declared. Please, define loop control variables like people normally do: `for(int i = 0;...`.

Comment: `stoi` will only work for short numbers, but you probably have to consider all substrings of the string with up to two thousand digits. You need to apply the modular arithmetic at a lower level.

Comment: Huh, ISRO uses a steel bar as a launch tower? -_-

Answer (score 1):

A little advice I can give you is to initialize a variable to `s.length()` to avoid calling the function each time for each `for` block.

Comment: This is a micro optimization. It is insignificant.

Comment: As I said, it's only a little advice, not a big code edit.

Comment: The `length()` member of a C++ string ist just an accessor; it doesn't have the same speed penalty as C's `strlen`. Such micro-optimisations may make the code a bit faster, but I think the real improvement lies in using a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here goes, with a working program at the bottom

### Major optimization #1

Do not (ever) work with strings when it comes to integer arithmetic. You're converting string => integer over and over and over again (this is an O(n^2) problem), which is painstakingly slow. Besides, it also misses the point.

Solution: first convert your array-of-characters (string) to array-of-numbers. Integer arithmetic is *fast*.

### Major optimization #2

Use a smart conversion from "substring" to number. After transforming the characters to actual integers, they become the factors in the the polynomial `a_n * 10^n`. To convert a substring of *n* segments into a number, it is enough to compute `sum(a_i * 10^i)` for `0 <= i < n`.

And nicely enough, if the coefficients a_i are arranged the way they are in the problem's statement, you can use Horner's method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to *very* quickly evaluate the numerical value of the substring.

In short: keep a running value of the current substring and growing it by one element is just `* 10 + new element`

Example: string "128472373".

- First substring = "1", value = 1.
- For the second substring we need to
  add the digit "2" as follows: `value = value * 10 + "2"`, thus: `value = 1 * 10 + 2 = 12`.
- For 3rd substring need to add digit "8": `value = value * 10 + "8"`, thus: `value = 12 * 10 + 8 = 128`.
- Etcetera.

I had some issues with formatting the C++ code inline so I stuck it in IDEone: https://ideone.com/TbJiqK

The gist of the program:

In main loop, loop over all possible start points:

```
// For all startpoints in the segments array ...
for(int* f=segments; f<segments+n_segments; f++)
    // add up the substrings that fullfill the question
    n += count_segments(f, segments+n_segments, m, l);
// Output the answer for this question
cout << n << endl;
```

Implementation of the `count_segments()` function:

```
// Find all substrings that % m == l
// Use Horner's algorithm to quickly evaluate sum(a_n*10^n) where
// a_n are the segments' durabilities
int count_segments(int* first, int* last, int m, int l) {
    int n = 0, number = 0;
    while( first<last ) {
        number = number * 10 + *first; // This is Horner's method
        if( (number % m)==l ) {
            n++;
            // If you don't believe - enable this line of output and
            // see the numbers matching the combinations of the
            //cout << "[" << m << ", " << l << "]: " << number << endl;
        }
        first++;
    }
    return n;
}
```